# Song title by stream wrong Encoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm working on a simple radio stream app for ios. I'm retriving song title with a KVO Observation of:

```
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"timedMetadata"])
    {

        for (AVMetadataItem* metadata in playerItem.timedMetadata)
        {
            if([metadata.commonKey isEqualToString:@"title"]){


            }
        }
    }
```

With this code i can get the title. Anyway whe there are some characthers i have this result:

```
deep grounder feat virÃ;g
```

instead of

```
deep grounder feat viràg
```

So i'm trying any solution to print the correct result in the screen. I have also tried:

```
NSString *StringaPassata=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"deep grounder feat virÃ;g"];               
NSData *data = [stringFromUTFString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];               NSString *newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The string remain the same... I have not control on the server that output the stream. To test the conversion i store in a NSString the string that cause the problem when it is downloaded from the server.
How i can convert to the string to the correct "à" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This Snippet I Have tried it

```
NSString *strYourKey = @"deep grounder feat viràg";
NSData *data = [strYourKey dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *dataToString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Your Converted Text is : %@", dataToString);
```

Output

```
[12134:168898] Your Converted Text is : deep grounder feat virag
```

Comment: thank you but the text i have to convert is "deep grounder feat virÃ;g" not "deep grounder feat viràg"

Comment: @user31929 can you please describe what output do you require?
input: - "deep grounder feat virÃ;g"
output:- "deep grounder feat virA;g" (snippet output)

Comment: input: - "deep grounder feat virÃ;g" output:- "deep grounder feat viràg"